# Logging will not overwrite existing log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, exception

I am new to logging and I'm attempting to write some code that will log uncaught exceptions in one of my programs. I have read the documentation and for some reason I am unable to do anything except append to a log file, which is not what I want. I've specified `filemode='w'` to no avail. Anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong in this situation?

Here is my error handler that has my logging code ( I have tried placing `logging.basicConfig` outside of the function but that did not seem to affect anything):

```
### Function that handles unexpected errors and dumps relevant information to a log file.
def exceptionhandler(etype, value, tb):
    # Checks if exception was manually raised.
    global has_been_called
    # If exception was not raised manually then it is uncaught.
    if has_been_called is not True:
            excmessage = 'Uncaught exception:\n'
            excmessage += ''.join(traceback.format_exception(etype, value, tb))
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="ERROR: Please send screenshot to Dev Team.",
                                           message=excmessage)
            logging.basicConfig(filename='Error.log', 
                    filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s',
                    level=DEBUG)
            logging.debug(excmessage)
    # Reset has_been_called to its default value.
    else:
        has_been_called = False
```

Comment: Also, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) say calling `basicConfig` adds a handler, which is a point made in answers to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925579/python-logger-wont-overwrite-the-original-log).

Comment: Yep, this was answered in the questions @cxw linked. Should I delete this question or wait for someone to mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: That's a good question - I actually don't know.  The closest advice I can find is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332101/2877364).  Based on that, I would say do not delete it.